# Reading P6 Activity ID (.xer and xml) via MPXJ for C#

Tags: c#, mpxj

MPXJ Version:5.1.17

Q1: If I export my p6 file to .xer . When I use MPXJ to read the file , I got garbled text in c#.(It's Chinese text originally),but if i export p6 file to XML format, i can get the right Chinese text using MPXJ in c#. Is anyone have such experience?

Q2: How can I get P6 Activity ID using MPXJ? the return type of Task.ID is Integer.. but the ID in P6 is string.
When I called MPXJ, I got

ID:6    // In XML, It's "A1010" , how can I get "A1010" ?

Sample XML Fragment

```
<Activity>
        <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration>
        <ActualFinishDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <ActualLaborCost>0</ActualLaborCost>
        <ActualLaborUnits>0</ActualLaborUnits>
        <ActualNonLaborCost>0</ActualNonLaborCost>
        <ActualNonLaborUnits>0</ActualNonLaborUnits>
        <ActualStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <ActualThisPeriodLaborCost>0</ActualThisPeriodLaborCost>
        <ActualThisPeriodLaborUnits>0</ActualThisPeriodLaborUnits>
        <ActualThisPeriodNonLaborCost>0</ActualThisPeriodNonLaborCost>
        <ActualThisPeriodNonLaborUnits>0</ActualThisPeriodNonLaborUnits>
        <AtCompletionDuration>8</AtCompletionDuration>
        <AtCompletionExpenseCost>0</AtCompletionExpenseCost>
        <AtCompletionLaborCost>0</AtCompletionLaborCost>
        <AtCompletionLaborUnits>0</AtCompletionLaborUnits>
        <AtCompletionNonLaborCost>0</AtCompletionNonLaborCost>
        <AtCompletionNonLaborUnits>0</AtCompletionNonLaborUnits>
        <AutoComputeActuals>0</AutoComputeActuals>
        <CalendarObjectId>178</CalendarObjectId>
        <DurationPercentComplete>0</DurationPercentComplete>
        <DurationType>Fixed Duration and Units</DurationType>
        <ExpectedFinishDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <ExternalEarlyStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <ExternalLateFinishDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <Feedback />
        <FinishDate>2016-01-18T16:00:00</FinishDate>
        <GUID>{255EF498-16AB-5041-B86B-F6F027FB3DF0}</GUID>
        <Id>A1010</Id>
        <IsNewFeedback>0</IsNewFeedback>
        <LevelingPriority>Normal</LevelingPriority>
        <Name>使用教學語系整合</Name>
        <NonLaborUnitsPercentComplete>0</NonLaborUnitsPercentComplete>
        <NotesToResources />
        <ObjectId>101718</ObjectId>
        <PercentComplete>0</PercentComplete>
        <PercentCompleteType>Duration</PercentCompleteType>
        <PhysicalPercentComplete>0</PhysicalPercentComplete>
        <PlannedDuration>8</PlannedDuration>
        <PlannedFinishDate>2016-01-18T16:00:00</PlannedFinishDate>
        <PlannedLaborCost>0</PlannedLaborCost>
        <PlannedLaborUnits>0</PlannedLaborUnits>
        <PlannedNonLaborCost>0</PlannedNonLaborCost>
        <PlannedNonLaborUnits>0</PlannedNonLaborUnits>
        <PlannedStartDate>2016-01-18T08:00:00</PlannedStartDate>
        <PrimaryConstraintDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <PrimaryConstraintType />
        <PrimaryResourceObjectId xsi:nil="true" />
        <ProjectObjectId>4508</ProjectObjectId>
        <RemainingDuration>8</RemainingDuration>
        <RemainingEarlyFinishDate>2016-01-18T16:00:00</RemainingEarlyFinishDate>
        <RemainingEarlyStartDate>2016-01-18T08:00:00</RemainingEarlyStartDate>
        <RemainingLaborCost>0</RemainingLaborCost>
        <RemainingLaborUnits>0</RemainingLaborUnits>
        <RemainingLateFinishDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <RemainingLateStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <RemainingNonLaborCost>0</RemainingNonLaborCost>
        <RemainingNonLaborUnits>0</RemainingNonLaborUnits>
        <ResumeDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <ReviewStatus>OK</ReviewStatus>
        <SecondaryConstraintDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <SecondaryConstraintType />
        <StartDate>2016-01-18T08:00:00</StartDate>
        <Status>Not Started</Status>
        <SuspendDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <Type>Task Dependent</Type>
        <UnitsPercentComplete>0</UnitsPercentComplete>
        <WBSObjectId>26012</WBSObjectId>
    </Activity>
```

Comment: If you have two questions you must open two different posts

Comment: Looks like a file encoding issue when reading the XER file. Can you open a bug on the SourceForge page and attach a sample XER file and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Jonlles OK , I have report it to [(https://sourceforge.net/p/mpxj/bugs/287/](https://sourceforge.net/p/mpxj/bugs/287/) , thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above regarding reporting the bug in reading the task name. To answer you second question the Activity ID is mapped into the `Text1` attribute of the task: `task.getText(1)` should get you what you want.